# Could I change the root of my sitemap.xml path?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

This is my resulting xml file.

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://localhost:5000/</loc>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

I would like to change http://localhost:5000 to https://www.mywebpage.es and I don't know where I've got to change it.
I tried to siteMapNode.Url = "...." + GetPath(); and it doesn't work or change my Mvc.sitemap. I need to have always the same root, developer environment or production environment...

Comment: I refer to UrlBase. Maybe, it's not possible

Comment: Did you use the sitemap package to generate the sitemap.xml file and want to change the root of the sitemap.xml? Could you share more details or a demo that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I takemy routes from Mvc.sitemap with 
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" url="/" />
from MyXmlSiteMapNodeProvider in this line
    List<ISiteMapNodeToParentRelation> siteMap = base.LoadSiteMapNodesFromXml(xml, helper).ToList()